# Spring logging in with any details

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ws

Does anyone know in Spring a way to implement a user-service or authentication provider that will accept any user when logging in?

This is further to my previous question: [spring-ws get username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460897/spring-ws-get-username-password/14468142#14468142)

I have a basic security setup in my spring-ws project:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.wsdl" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="me" password="mypass"
                authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I don't want to specify users in the user-service, I want a user with any details to have access, I simply want to make sure the user gives a username and password and to ensure that I can access this from the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Is it necessary to implement my own user-service or authentication-provider to do this and if so can anyone point in the direction of an example or provide me with one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide your own `AuthenticationProvider` i.e. an implementation of the `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider` interface.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider ref="myProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="myProvider" class="MyProvider"/>
```

`MyProvider` can then either delegate to a custom `UserDetailsService` to set the authorieties (the roles) or set a `ROLE_USER` directly.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work implementing my own AuthenticationProvider

Answer (score 0):

if you change

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
```

to

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
```

you can then set your intercepts from

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/*.wsdl" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

to

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/*.wsdl" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

that will allow any authenticated user access to those url patterns.

Comment: That's only half the story as you still need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to fake authentication (accept any user/pw combination).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

Configure your intercept URL to provide access to any role names. You can do this by doing the following:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.wsdl" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
     <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Create your own user service which grants at least one authority to the user for any username and password combination.
Configure spring security to use the service you created.

```
<bean id="userService" class="com.ek.UserService" />
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I hope this gives you the idea on what you need to do. Else, we can work on creating a sample code for you.

Comment: That's only half the story as you still need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to fake authentication (accept any user/pw combination).